# @Html.DeleteConfirmation in a Plugin View (Admin) in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, asp.net-core-2.0, nopcommerce-4.0

Looking at core code examples of say... Edit Action for SpecificationAttribute. I am looking to replicate this delete function in the same manner in my plugin, however, getting an error.

Getting this error

> 'IHtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DeleteConfirmation' and no extension method 'DeleteConfirmation' accepting a first argument of type 'IHtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have used in 3.90 but it getting error in 4.0 asp.net core Has anyone used `@Html.DeleteConfirmation` in a plugin (on administration side) that could give me a clues

I have a span element in the html like the following;

```
<span id="myattribute-delete" class="k-button">@T("Admin.Common.Delete")</span>
```

And trying to use `@Html.DeleteConfirmation("myattribute-delete")`

I know I probably need to double check my route, by the error is leading me to think the issue is not a routing issue.

Comment: Can you add the `error` message?

Comment: @Hackerman i have edit the post please can you review this.

Comment: What is your `DeleteConfirmation()` method (that is not part of MVC), and how have you registered it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Stephen stated it's not part of MVC, and it's custom helper by nopCommerce.

`@Html.DeleteConfirmation` is helper till/in nopCommerce 3.90, but in 4.0 it has been changed to

```
<nop-delete-confirmation asp-model-id="@Model.Id" asp-button-id="myattribute-delete" />
```

And that helper located at `Nop.Web.Framework.TagHelpers.Admin`so you have to add reference of it to your view file.

Comment: @ILYASPATEL Glad I could help :)